# Ensuring lexicographical sort in pandas MultiIndex

Tags: pandas

I've got some data with a MultiIndex (some timing stats, with index levels for "device", "build configuration", "tested function", etc). I want to slice out on some of those index columns.

It seems like "slicers" to the .loc function are probably the way to go. However the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers) contain this warning:

> Warning: You will need to make sure that the selection axes are fully lexsorted!

Later on in the docs there's a section on [The Need for Sortedness with MultiIndex](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#the-need-for-sortedness-with-multiindex) which says

> you are responsible for ensuring that things are properly sorted

but thankfully,

> The MultiIndex object has code to explicity check the sort depth. Thus, if you try to index at a depth at which the index is not sorted, it will raise an exception.

Sounds fine.

However the remaining question is how does one get their data properly sorted for the indexing to work properly? The docs talk about an important new method `sortlevel()` but then contains the following caveat:

> There is an important new method sortlevel to sort an axis within a MultiIndex so that its labels are grouped and sorted by the original ordering of the associated factor at that level. Note that this does not necessarily mean the labels will be sorted lexicographically!

In my case, sortlevel() did the right thing, but what if my "original ordering of the associated factor" was not sorted? Is there a simple one-liner that I can use on any MultiIndex-ed DataFrame to ensure it's ready for slicing and fully lexsorted?

---

Edit: My exploration suggests most ways of creating a MultiIndex automatically lexsorts the unique labels when building the index. Example:

```
In [1]: 
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['b','d','b','a'], 'col2': [3,1,1,2],
                  'data':['one','two','three','four']})
df

Out[1]: 
  col1  col2   data
0    b     3    one
1    d     1    two
2    b     1  three
3    a     2   four

In [2]:
df2 = df.set_index(['col1','col2'])
df2

Out[2]: 
            data
col1 col2       
b    3       one
d    1       two
b    1     three
a    2      four

In [3]: df2.index
Out[3]: 
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'a', u'b', u'd'], [1, 2, 3]],
           labels=[[1, 2, 1, 0], [2, 0, 0, 1]],
           names=[u'col1', u'col2'])
```

Note how the unique items in the levels array are lexsorted, even though the DataFrame object is  itself is not. Then, as expected:

```
In [4]: df2.index.is_lexsorted()
Out[4]: False

In [5]: 
sorted = df2.sortlevel()
sorted
Out[5]: 
            data
col1 col2       
a    2      four
b    1     three
     3       one
d    1       two

In [6]: sorted.index.is_lexsorted()
Out[6]: True
```

However, if the levels are explicitly ordered so they are not sorted, things get weird:

```
In [7]:
df3 = df2
df3.index.set_levels(['b','d','a'], level='col1', inplace=True)
df3.index.set_labels([0,1,0,2], level='col1', inplace=True)
df3

Out[7]: 
            data
col1 col2       
b    3       one
d    1       two
b    1     three
a    2      four

In [8]:
sorted2 = df3.sortlevel()
sorted2

Out[8]: 
            data
col1 col2       
b    1     three
     3       one
d    1       two
a    2      four

In [9]: sorted2.index.is_lexsorted()
Out[9]: True

In [10]: sorted2.index
Out[10]: 
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'b', u'd', u'a'], [1, 2, 3]],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 0, 1]],
           names=[u'col1', u'col2'])
```

So sorted2 is reporting that it is lexsorted, when in fact it is not. This feels a little like what the warning in the docs is getting at, but it's still not clear how to fix it or whether it's really an issue at all.

Comment: The [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sortlevel.html#pandas.DataFrame.sortlevel) seem to indicate that it will sort lexicographically maybe that section is out of date?

Comment: I've been playing with this a bit more - it seems like most methods to generate the MultiIndex sort the unique values within each level on creation, eg MultiIndex.from_tuples(('b',2),('a',1)) ends up with levels=[['a','b'],[1,2]], labels=[[1,0],[1,0]]. Using set_levels on the index does allow specifically setting un-ordered levels. I read the bit you've quoted as meaning if a level has level=['b','a'], labels=[1,1,0,1,0] (ie 5 rows, aabab) that it would reorder the rows so that labels is sorted, but not reorder the levels lexographically - eg result would be bbaaa). Still exploring...

Comment: Ah, I think your reading comprehension is better than mine (so I deleted my prior comment).  It's a subtler point than I was expecting there and isn't demonstrated in the example.  I'll be happy to +1 that if you are correct and want to show an example and write it up in an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the +1 offer! I have more of an understanding of what's going on now, but still not actually answered my question about if there's a simple one-liner to ensure the DataFrame is fully lexsorted so I won't put it as an answer. Might do an edit to the question later on with some examples of what I've found so far

Answer (score 1):

As far as sorting, as @EdChum pointed out, the docs [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sortlevel.html#pandas.DataFrame.sortlevel) seem to indicate it is lexicographically sorted.

For checking whether your index (or columns) are sorted, they have a method `is_lexsorted()` and an attribute `lexsort_depth` (which for some reason you can't really find in the documentation itself).

Example:

Create a Series with random order

```
In [1]:
import pandas as pd
arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'],
            ['one', 'two', '1', '3', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two']]

tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
import random; random.shuffle(tuples)
s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(8), index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples))
s

Out[1]:
baz  3     -0.191653
qux  two   -1.410311
bar  one   -0.336475
qux  one   -1.192908
foo  two    0.486401
baz  1      0.888314
foo  one   -1.504816
bar  two    0.917460
dtype: float64
```

Check is_lexsorted and lexsort_depth:

```
In [2]: s.index.is_lexsorted()
Out[2]: False

In [3]: s.index.lexsort_depth
Out[3]: 0
```

Sort the index, and recheck the values:

```
In [4]: s = s.sortlevel(0, sort_remaining=True)
        s

Out[4]:
bar  one   -0.336475
     two    0.917460
baz  1      0.888314
     3     -0.191653
foo  one   -1.504816
     two    0.486401
qux  one   -1.192908
     two   -1.410311
dtype: float64

In [5]: s.index.is_lexsorted()
Out[5]: True

In [6]: s.index.lexsort_depth  
Out[6]: 2
```

Comment: Thanks Julien. I think MultiIndex.from_tuples ensures the factors are lexsorted in each level when building the index, so this doesn't trigger the warning the docs are talking about. See my edit to the question.

Comment: I think this question is a bit out of hand :) I was trying to answer 'Is there a simple one-liner that I can use on any MultiIndex-ed DataFrame to ensure it's ready for slicing and fully lexsorted?' and I think I about did no?

Comment: The sorted2 in my edit reports that it is lexsorted but in fact is not. The behaviour instead matches the l caveat in the docs I quoted that says sortlevels does not ensure the labels in each level are sorted.