# Is the list of levels in a Pandas dataframe guaranteed to be sorted?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

When creating a Pandas dataframe with a MultiIndex, the levels seem to always be sorted:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame([range(4)], columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["b", "a"], [20, 10]]))
   b     a
  20 10 20 10
0  0  1  2  3

>>> _.columns
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'a', u'b'], [10, 20]],
           labels=[[1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0]])
```

(Note how `levels` is sorted.) Is this guaranteed? Knowing this can help write robust code (since we can then rely on a simple property of MultiIndices).

I can't find any guarantee in the documentation (but then this doesn't mean that it couldn't be there!).

There are also [old examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31427466/ensuring-lexicographical-sort-in-pandas-multiindex) (from 2015) that show a different behavior, but maybe does Pandas now offer guarantees on the ordering of levels (in the same way as Python 3.6 offers a guarantee on the order of keys in dictionaries)?

Answer (score 3):

When creating a `MultiIndex` using `from_product()` or `from_arrays()` levels will be sorted because both methods use `_factorize_from_iterables()` which returns the indexes sorted.

```
>> list(_factorize_from_iterables([["b", "a"], [20, 10]]))

[[array([1, 0], dtype=int8), array([1, 0], dtype=int8)],
 [Index(['a', 'b'], dtype='object'), Int64Index([10, 20], dtype='int64')]]
```

`MultiIndex.from_tuples()` will also have sorted levels because it uses `from_arrays()` internally.

If you set `MultiIndex` without specifying a method however, levels won't be sorted.

```
>> midx = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[['b', 'a'], [20, 10]],
                                      labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1]])
>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4,4), columns=midx)

>> df.columns

MultiIndex(levels=[['b', 'a'], [20, 10]],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1]])
```

Above uses `pandas` version `0.22.0` (released in december 29, 2017) and is tested on version `0.23.4` (latest release).

Comment: Good point, about the manual creation of an index. Now the question for the Pandas community is whether the sorting behavior of the MultiIndex creation functions could be guaranteed in the documentation (and through backward compatibility).